# Echoing input into a select prompt produces unexpected behaviour

Tags: bash

I am trying to automate selecting options in a list. When I have chosen Select All from a previous list, to go through each file I have to select 1 then 6, repeatedly. until I have gone through all the files. I would like to be able to automate this, so that after I have selected 1, I then select 4, then it automatically selects 1 and 6 for the rest of the files.

I have tried starting with echoing just 1 into the select prompt and it works but not as expected. It selects option 1 and outputs the information but rather than stopping there, it goes to the next file and selects option 1 until it has gone through all the files.

Why does it do this behaviour and how can I get it to work as expected?

```
listVideoActions() {
    local numVideos=$((${#VIDEOLIST[@]}))
    actions=("Show video information"
             "Search name on opensubtitles"
             "Search hash on opensubtitles"
             "Repeat last action for all files"
             "Go back to video selection"
    )
    #Add conditional actions. If the Select All option was picked a "Next Video"
    #action is needed to go though all the videos, otherwise just add a "Quit" action
    if [ $# -eq 3 ] && [ $3 -lt $numVideos ]; then actions+=("Next video"); actions+=("Quit")
    else actions+=("Quit"); fi

    printf "${BBlue}$2${Color_Off}\n"
    PS3="Select an action: "

    echo 1 | select action in "${actions[@]}"; do
        printf "\n"
        if   [ $REPLY = 1 ]; then displayVideoInformation "$1"
        elif [ $REPLY = 2 ]; then searchNameOpensubtitles "$1"
        elif [ $REPLY = 3 ]; then searchHashOpensubtitles "$1"
        #elif [ $REPLY = 4 ]; then repeatLast
        elif [ $REPLY = 5 ]; then listVideos;
        elif [ $REPLY = 6 ] && [ $# -eq 3 ] && [ $3 -lt $numVideos ]; then break
        elif [ $REPLY = 6 ]; then exit 1
        elif [ $REPLY = 7 ] && [ $# -eq 3 ] && [ $3 -lt $numVideos ]; then exit 1; fi
    done
}
```

The call to `listVideoActions()`

```
i=1
for video in "${VIDEOLIST[@]}"; do
    listVideoActions "$video" "${video##*/}" $i
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: Add a `break` command just before `done`

Comment: That doesn't do anything, I even tried adding `exit` instead and that did nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this with `yes` instead of `echo`.

```
selectVideoAction() {
    # Needed so listVideoActions can do a check to see if a 5 was the
    # last $REPLY before a 6
    [ "$REPLY" != 6 ] && lReply="$REPLY"

    [ $allSelected -eq 1 ] && PS3="Select an action($lAction): "\
                           || PS3="Select an action: "
    printf "\n"

    [ "$REPLY" = 2 ] && displayVideoInformation "$1" && lAction=$REPLY
    [ "$REPLY" = 3 ] && searchNameOpensubtitles "$1" && lAction=$REPLY
    [ "$REPLY" = 4 ] && searchHashOpensubtitles "$1" && lAction=$REPLY
}

listVideoActions() {
    local actions=("Go back to video selection")            # 1
    actions+=("Show video information")                     # 2 repeatable
    actions+=("Search name on opensubtitles")               # 3 repeatable
    actions+=("Search hash on opensubtitles")               # 4 repeatable
    [ $allSelected -eq 1 ] && actions+=("Next video")      `# 5` \
    && actions+=("Repeat last action on remaining files");  # 6
    actions+=("Quit")                                       # 5 or 7

    printf "${BBlue}$2${Color_Off}\n"
    [ $allSelected -eq 1 ] && PS3="Select an action($lAction): "\
                           || PS3="Select an action: "

    if [ $repeatLast -eq 0 ]; then
        select action in "${actions[@]}"; do
            selectVideoAction "$1"

            if   [ "$REPLY" = 1 ]; then allSelected=0; break;
            elif [ "$REPLY" = 5 ]  && [ $allSelected -eq 1 ]; then break
            elif [ "$REPLY" = 5 ]  && [ $allSelected -eq 0 ]; then exit 1
            elif [ "$REPLY" = 6 ]  && [ $allSelected -eq 1 ]; then
                # Check that a repeatable action has previously been selected
                if [ ! -z "$lAction" ]; then
                    # If the previous action $REPLY was to go to the next video
                    # then the repeatable action needs to be run before going
                    # to the next video
                    [ "$lReply" = 5 ] && REPLY=$lAction && selectVideoAction "$1"

                    repeatLast=1
                    break
                fi
                PS3="No last action. Select an action($lAction): "
            elif [ "$REPLY" = 7 ]  && [ $allSelected -eq 1 ]; then exit 1; fi
        done
    elif [ $repeatLast -eq 1 ]; then
        # Run the last repeatable action automatically for every remaining video
        sleep 2 | yes "$lAction" | select action in "${actions[@]}"; do
            selectVideoAction "$1"
            break
        done
    fi
}

listVideos() {
    local lReply=""       # The last action $REPLY
    local lAction=""      # The last repeatable action $REPLY 2, 3 or 4
    local repeatLast=0    # When set to 1 $lAction is automatically repeated
    local allSelected=0   # When set to 1 all videos have been selected
    local options=("${videos[@]}")  
          options+=("Select All")
    local numOptions=$((${#options[@]}))
    PS3="Select a video: "

    select file in "${options[@]##*/}"; do
        # Strip all spaces so arithmetic(( )) comparison doesn't fail
        REPLY=$(echo "$REPLY" | tr -d ' ')
        printf "\n"

        if [ "$REPLY" = "$numOptions" ]; then
            allSelected=1
            local video

            for video in "${videos[@]}"; do
                listVideoActions "$video" "${video##*/}"
                # The action $REPLY 1 was selected to return to the video list 
                [ $allSelected -eq 0 ] && break
            done
            break
        elif (( "$REPLY" > 0 && "$REPLY" < "$numOptions" )); then
            listVideoActions "${videos[$REPLY-1]}" "${videos[$REPLY-1]##*/}"
            break
        fi
    done
    listVideos
}
```